# Как НЕ запускать новый таймер, если уже запущен

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, таймер

подскажите пожалуйста, не получается разобраться. Создаю телеграм-бота. При нажатии на кнопку должен запускаться таймер. При **повторном** нажатии - если таймер уже запущен, пользователь должен быть уведомлен об этом. В противном случае логично - должен начинаться новый таймер. В коде ниже у меня не получается выполнять проверку, таймер всегда запускается повторно при нажатии на кнопку(кнопка в примере ниже: "Герой". Вероятно я логически не правильно мыслю и создавать такие таймеры/потоки нужно по другому.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def buttons(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == '‍♂️Герой':

            def hello():
                print ('hello')

            t = threading.Timer(4, hello)

            if t.is_alive():
                print('wait to end')
            else: 
                t.start()
                print('timer is up')
```

Comment: Если я выношу создание потокового таймера до объявления метода с кнопкой, то получаю: threads can only be started once

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def buttons(message):
    timer_exists = False
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == '‍♂️Герой':

            def hello():
                print ('hello')

            if not timer_exists:
                t = threading.Timer(4, hello)
                timer_exists = True

            if t.is_alive():
                print('wait to end')
            else: 
                t.start()
                print('timer is up')
```

Comment: Сомневаюсь что сработает, ведь timer_exists не глобальная переменная, она при вызове хендлера всегда будет False.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: К сожалению да, проблема осталась. Работает, но таймер запускается каждый раз при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать её в проекте глобальной

Comment: Если я выношу ее до вызова хэндлера, тогда при обработке кнопки "Герой" он ее не видит: local variable 'timer_exists' referenced before assignment